# multiple usb hid connect a single pc by hub usb

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I have a little problem.
I bought 5 hid usb rfid readers. I have connected via a USB hub to a single PC. I have created software that I take the data I get from these readers.
These readers read an id within some card.

If step the card one by one in the different reader readers, it all works.
The problem is that when I pass the card in the reader at the same time, I get all the wrong data.

for example:
if the id of the card 1 is 1234567808
id card 2 is 9876543212

.
If I read both card  same time not receive:
  12345678089876543212

but I get the numbers all mixed up, how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Do these readers just simulate keyboards and type the numbers into whatever text field is in focus? In that case you'd have to write a client that selectively enables only one keyboard at a time (and switches between them periodically to see if there's input) or talks directly to the readers.